# Stock quote checking script

Tags: python, finance

I know that this code would look a lot better if I made it so that checking the current prices against the open prices were in a function. This would avoid rewriting it for every stock I want to check. But I'm not sure how to get started on doing that properly. Do any of you have some tips to get me started?

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

apple = Share('AAPL')

appleopen = float(apple.get_open())
applecurrent = float(apple.get_price())

if appleopen > applecurrent:
    print(("Apple is down for the day. Current price is"), applecurrent)
else:
    print(("Apple is up for the day! Current price is "), applecurrent)

applechange = (applecurrent - appleopen)
if applechange > 0:
    print(('The price moved'),abs(applechange),("to the upside today."))
else:
    print(('The priced moved'),abs(applechange),("to the downside today."))
print('-----------------------')
nflx = Share('NFLX')

nflxopen = float(nflx.get_open())
nflxcurrent = float(nflx.get_price())

if nflxopen > nflxcurrent:
    print(("Netflix is down for the day. Current price is"), nflxcurrent)
else:
    print(("Netflix is up for the day! Current price is "), nflxcurrent)

nflxchange = (nflxcurrent - nflxopen)
if nflxchange > 0:
    print(('The price moved'),abs(nflxchange),("to the upside today."))
else:
    print(('The priced moved'),abs(nflxchange),("to the downside today."))
```

Comment: Non-technical note: I'm unfamiliar with the Yahoo Finance library, but bear in mind that stock movements should not be calculated based on the open price for a day. Last price would be preferable, so that it changes as you check through the day. For example, a stock I own shares in plummeted 3% yesterday morning, but finished the day positive. Your script - if run in the afternoon - would have still have told me it was "down for the day".

Comment: oh jeez, great catch @scarl3tt! thank you for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you yourself noted, you need a function:

```
def financial_info(acronym):
    company = Share(acronym)

    company_open = float(company.get_open())
    company_current = float(company.get_price())

    if company_open > company_current:
        print(company, " is down for the day. Current price is ", company_current)
    else:
        print(company, " is up for the day! Current price is ", company_current)

    # ...
```

I just wrote a part of it, you sure are able to finish it :)